# Executing Python with PHP and returning results to a Div

Tags: php, python, jquery

I have been able to successfully execute a python script and return the result to the empty div. It was done using a simple python script (test.py) that returns "hello world". However, the python script I want to execute is significantly more complex with dependencies and includes arguments.

```
$cmd = 'python /home/pi/st/staging/st1.6.1/st.py 1 1';
$command = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
$command = escapeshellcmd('python ../testing/test.py'); // this works and is normally commented out
$output = exec($command);
echo($output);
```

I am wondering if I need to add all the dependencies to the www-data group and chmod them to be executable in order for this to work. The st.py script could take up to an hour to complete. I am building a web interface to run various tasks on a Raspberry Pi automated machine.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. Are you asking how to get more data into the Python script? If so, you can add more parameters to the Python scripts and pass them down. Like `python /your/script.py -a parameterOne -b parameterTwo`

Comment: Hint: you only need escapeshellcmd if user input is part of the command line. Not a good idea to invoke the py scipt this way if it will run for an hour.

Comment: I am not looking for methods to pass parameters. I am interested in how to get the st.py script to run. The hello world script runs fine.

Comment: I am using escapeshellcmd because I am anticipating user input. I haven't decided on whether I will do user input as a permanent solution or not. For the moment, I just need that script to run and return the results to the screen to monitor the machine during the testing phase.